# Copying images, logos, objects to new sheets with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have created (with some considerable help from superior programmers) a workbook with a master sheet for inputting grades, and a macro for exporting the template (A1:C63), along with separate columns of information (D to Q) to separate sheets (which always appear in D1:D63 of the new sheet along side the template). The new sheets are named after the student names in row 7 of their respective columns in the master sheet.

Here's the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub parse_data()
    Dim studsSht As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim stud As Variant

    Set studsSht = Worksheets("Input") '<--| change "Sheet1" to your actual students grades sheet
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") '<--| instantiate a Dictionary object
        For Each cell In studsSht.Range("D7:Q7").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) '<--| loop through students names (change "D7:Q7" to your actual range with students names)
            .Item(cell.Value) = .Item(cell.Value) & cell.EntireColumn.Address(False, False) & "," '<--| add or update the dictionary entry whose key is the current student name with its corresponding column address
        Next
        For Each stud In .keys '<--| loop through unique students names
            Intersect(studsSht.UsedRange, studsSht.Range(Left(.Item(stud), Len(.Item(stud)) - 1))).Copy Destination:=GetSheet(CStr(stud)).Range("D1") '<--| copy its columns to correspondingly named sheet starting from cell A1
        Next
    End With

    studsSht.Activate
End Sub

Function GetSheet(shtName As String) As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set GetSheet = Worksheets(shtName)
If GetSheet Is Nothing Then
    Set GetSheet = Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    GetSheet.Name = shtName
    Sheets("Input").Range("A1:C63").Copy
    GetSheet.Range("A1:D63").PasteSpecial xlAll
End If
End Function
```

What I would like to know is if I can add to the code a way to carry over images (school logos, in fact) from the master sheet to the same location in the new sheets? I assume, since images are not attached to cells, that it makes no difference where they're located on the master sheet and that some other way of locating/identifying them must be necessary.

I thought, since all my sheets are formatted in the same way, there was a way to use a distance measuring system within excel for this. I've heard mention of such a thing but I'll be damned if I can find out anything about it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By far the easiest way is to create an empty "template" worksheet, hide it, and then copy the hidden template when you add new ones.

Comment: If you really want to copy the image then the TopLeftCell Property of the image might help.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I understand the concept, but lack the skills to carry it out. Forgive me for being dense, but how would I link the template to the functionality of the worksheet? I mean, is there a way to place the logos on a hidden sheet in the position I need them (I can do that bit) and layer them over the new sheets as they are generated, all as part of the macro? I don't mind if you send me somewhere else to find out. I want to learn how, not have someone do it for me.

Comment: Actually, I found this. I think I can modify it to work `ActiveSheet.Shapes("Your Chart").Left = Sheet1.Cells(3, 2).Left
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Your Chart").Top = Sheet1.Cells(3, 2).Top
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Your Chart").Height = Sheet1.Range("G3:G7").Height
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Your Chart").Width = Sheet1.Range("B7:G7").Width`

Comment: Instead of `Sheets.Add`, use `HiddenSheet.Copy` where `HiddenSheet` is the code name of your template.

Comment: I tried that, and it bugged. In fact, the current macro basically copies the input page and the logos don't go, so I don't see how copying a hidden sheet would help.